# Aggregate a Dataset

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, aggregate

How do i aggregate(using linq) the value of one column of a Dataset where the other column is the same.

For example, my columns are

```
Row1  Row2  

2     3  
4     5  
6     7  
2     2  
6     4  
7     4  
2     4
```

I need something like this

```
Row1 Row2  

2    9  
4    5  
6    11  
7    4
```

edit: the values in "Row2" are the number of "Row1". so the values of (for example: 2) have to be aggregated into a new datatable where is only a single entry for (2).
**I'm sorry if the question is vague.**

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747.aspx#sumSimple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ to aggregate rows and copy the results to a new table:

```
DataTable source = // whatever
DataTable dest = source.Clone();

var aggregate = source
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("Row1"))
    .Select(grp => new { Row1 = grp.Key, Row2 = grp.Select(r => r.Field<int>("Row2")).Sum() });

foreach(var row in aggregate)
{
    dest.Rows.Add(new object[] { row.Row1, row.Row2 });
}
```

Comment: @Sam, @Lee: I strongly recommend you to use `IEnumerable<T>.CopyToDataTable() where T : DataRow` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx

Comment: How can we refactor this code to make it work for N number of columns ?

Comment: Please suggest for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537162/aggregate-datatable-with-dynamic-number-of-columns?noredirect=1#comment36108652_23537162

Answer (score 1):

Add reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`

```
DataSet ds = ..
DataTable table = ds.Tables[0]; // or ds.Tables["YourTableName"];

var q = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
        group row by row.Field<int>("Row1") into g
        select new
        {
            Row1 = g.Key,
            Row2 = g.Sum(s => s.Field<int>("Row2"))
        };
```

If you need group by several columns:

```
var q = from record in table.AsEnumerable()
        group record by new { Row1 = record.Field<int>("Row1"), Row2 = record.Field<int>("Row3") } into g
        select new
        {
            Row1 = g.Key,
            Row2 = g.Sum(s => s.Field<int>("Row2"))
        };
```

Comment: @abatishchev: What is g.Key here. I was looking at link provided by me and was trying to understand it. Could you please provide some explanation on it.

Comment: @Shantanu: `g.Key` is a key by which you're grouping, in current case - `row.Field<int>("Row1")`

Comment: @abatishchev: What if I had 3 or more columns in that case I had to do group by on all remaining columns. In that case how would it have worked.

Comment: @Shantanu: Very good post about nested grouping using LINQ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442425/nested-group-by-in-linq

Answer (score 0):

If you don't (want to) use Linq you can try [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326145) Microsoft HOWTO and create your own helper class.