# Aggregate datatable with dynamic number of columns

Tags: c#, dataset, linq-to-dataset

I have a datatable with dynamic set of columns and want to aggregate the numeric based columns and keep the final rows into new datatable.

DataTable Sample:-

```
PartnerName   CreditCol  DebitCol  AmountCol ....
P1              10       20        30 
P2              1        2         3 
P3              3        1         10
P2              1        100       200
```

**The desired output should be :-**

```
PartnerName   CreditCol  DebitCol  AmountCol ....
P1              10       20        30 
P2              2        102       203 
P3              3        1         10
```

The main thing here is the column set and **will be dynamic**. Sometime, there could be two columns and sometimes it could be 20 cols.  Please suggest the linq query or any other solution.

Comment: Is the type of the columns that you want to aggregate always `int`? Is the column you want to group-by always one column or can it be a combination of muultiple columns? Have you tried anything?

Comment: The primary key will be based on one column i.e. PartnerName. For numeric column, it could be string. But we have to cast it to int for aggregation.

Comment: and you want it to check every column if all values in all rows can be parsed to `int`? Can't you provide the columns that you want to sum? What if a column contains `"10.0"`? That's clearly not an `int` but it could be parsed to `decimal` which could be converted to an `int` or summed to a decimal value with decimal places.

Comment: I tried to perform with the datarow iteration but it was getting complex. I am new to Linq and may be its easy to manipulate in the linq query.

Comment: It will always contain integer data, nothing to worry for decimals. But the column set could vary. We can skip the parsing check if it is a pricey evaluation..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a dynamic approach that should work for your requirement:

```
var rows = table.AsEnumerable();
var columns = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>();
int i;  // used to check if a string column can be parsed to int
string columnToGroup = "partnername";
DataColumn colToGroup = columns.First(c => c.ColumnName.Equals(columnToGroup, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
var colsToSum = columns
     .Where(c => c != colToGroup &&
         (c.DataType == typeof(int) ||
         (c.DataType == typeof(string)
         && rows.All(r => int.TryParse(r.Field<string>(c), out i)))));
var columnsToSum = new HashSet<DataColumn>(colsToSum);

DataTable tblSum = table.Clone(); // empty table, same schema
foreach (var group in rows.GroupBy(r => r[colToGroup]))
{
    DataRow row = tblSum.Rows.Add();
    foreach(var col in columns)
    {
        if (columnsToSum.Contains(col))
        {
            int sum;
            if (col.DataType == typeof(int))
                sum = group.Sum(r => r.Field<int>(col));
            else
                sum = group.Sum(r => int.Parse(r.Field<string>(col)));
            row.SetField(col.ColumnName, sum);
        }
        else
            row[col.ColumnName] = group.First()[col];
    }
}
```

Tested with your sample data here:

```
var table = new System.Data.DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("PartnerName", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("CreditCol", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("DebitCol", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("AmountCol", typeof(int));
table.Rows.Add("P1", 10, "20", 30);
table.Rows.Add("P2", 1, "2", 3);
table.Rows.Add("P3", 3, "1", 10);
table.Rows.Add("P2", 1, "100", 200);
```

Result:

```
PartnerName   CreditCol    DebitCol    AmountCol
P1            10             20         30
P2            2              102        203
P3            3              1          10
```

Comment: Thanks for the soln, Let me try and keep you posted.